# My discord.py bot always loses connection to my MySQL database on Heroku

Tags: python, mysql, heroku, discord.py, mysql-connector-python

So, I've got a problem with my bot hosted on Heroku. Indeed, my bot manages a level system that I've made with MySQL. My system seems to be working perfectly, but, only for a few minutes after starting the bot. During this period, all the commands are working. After 5 minutes, at least, that my bot has started, no more command related to the database works. When a command is written, the logs write this:

```
2020-10-08T21:51:00.344273+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in on_message
2020-10-08T21:51:00.346163+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-10-08T21:51:00.346212+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 333, in _run_event
2020-10-08T21:51:00.346213+00:00 app[worker.1]: await coro(*args, **kwargs)
2020-10-08T21:51:00.346215+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "pabBot.py", line 96, in on_message
2020-10-08T21:51:00.346217+00:00 app[worker.1]: await upgrade_level(message.author, message)
2020-10-08T21:51:00.346236+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "pabBot.py", line 19, in upgrade_level
2020-10-08T21:51:00.346238+00:00 app[worker.1]: cursor.execute("SELECT exp, lvl, exp_time FROM level_users WHERE id=%s;", (user.id, ))
2020-10-08T21:51:00.346241+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 551, in execute
2020-10-08T21:51:00.346241+00:00 app[worker.1]: self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
2020-10-08T21:51:00.346262+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
2020-10-08T21:51:00.346263+00:00 app[worker.1]: result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
2020-10-08T21:51:00.346281+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 267, in _send_cmd
2020-10-08T21:51:00.346281+00:00 app[worker.1]: return self._socket.recv()
2020-10-08T21:51:00.346300+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 243, in recv_plain
2020-10-08T21:51:00.346300+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise errors.InterfaceError(errno=2013)
2020-10-08T21:51:00.346325+00:00 app[worker.1]: mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
2020-10-08T21:51:00.346399+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in command level:
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347478+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347541+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347541+00:00 app[worker.1]: ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347557+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "pabBot.py", line 168, in level
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347557+00:00 app[worker.1]: cursor.execute("SELECT exp, lvl FROM level_users WHERE id=%s", (user.id, ))
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347572+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 551, in execute
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347572+00:00 app[worker.1]: self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347574+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347574+00:00 app[worker.1]: result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347591+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 267, in _send_cmd
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347591+00:00 app[worker.1]: return self._socket.recv()
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347594+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 243, in recv_plain
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347595+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise errors.InterfaceError(errno=2013)
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347622+00:00 app[worker.1]: mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347625+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347625+00:00 app[worker.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347625+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347641+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347669+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347669+00:00 app[worker.1]: await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347688+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 859, in invoke
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347688+00:00 app[worker.1]: await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347709+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347709+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
2020-10-08T21:51:00.347734+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: InterfaceError: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Here is my *requirements.txt*:

```
discord.py
dnspython==1.16.0
mysql-connector
```

Of course, I noticed that the error is:
`mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

I've been looking for information about this error, and I didn't really get it.
I still don't know if the error is an server-side error, or client-side, or if it's because of my code. For information, my database is hosted on **remotemysql.com**.
Also, I tried to reproduce the error locally, and it works too. So, I don't think the error comes from Heroku.

My code is very large, so I don't think it's a good idea to send it in full, but I have some fonctions that allow me to check my level, someone else's level and to make a leaderboard.

If you guys know why my bot doesn't work and what the error is about, i'll gladly take your information! Also, if you need more details, i'll send them.

(Sorry for my bad english, I'm a french guy ^^')

Answer (score 0):

It's me again.. Turns out I figured out where my error came from, I did a lot of tests, only to realize that I stupidly forgot to close the connection at the end of my commands, and to reconnect it when a new one was written...

So I wanted to apologize for this completely unnecessary question, and to thank those who have seen it and who may have sought to help me.

(If you have any other suggestion to make, I will gladly take them!)

Bye!